# Why 'IsDBNull' returns false for field that is NULLable in the DB?

Tags: c#, mysql, sqldatareader

I read data from DB using 'IDataReader' and simple query

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY Id
```

The problem is that call to

```
reader.IsDBNull(i)
```

return 'false' even for nullable fields...

and call to

```
reader.GetValue(i)
```

returns 0 if value in those fields is NULL.

Please advise how to get NULL properly?

P.S.

I believe I have something wrong with configuring connection string to access data, so here it is:

```
<add key="ConnectionString.MySql.Data.DataProvider.MySqlDataProvider.MySql"
    value="server=***; user id=***; pwd=***; database=***; Convert Zero Datetime=true;"
    />
```

P.S. Yes, I work with MySql, v.5.1

**P.P.S. My bad: used data from the wrong DB that has actually 0 value. Please delete the question.**

Comment: Closing as "too localized" due to it being a simple value error; I'm preferring "closed, too localized" to *delete* simply because it has a correct and upvoted answer provided

Comment: This was simply a mistake on your part, but the question is still valid and you're probably not the only person to ask it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> return 'false' even for nullable fields...

`reader.IsDBNull` returns true if the record against the field is `null`, it doesn't tell whether the data type is nullable or not.

Comment: My bad: used data from the wrong DB that has actually 0 value. Please delete the question. Actually, didn't have confidence i do everything properly. Thank you for answer

Comment: @Budda, you are welcome, and don't worry about accessing wrong DB, believe me, it happens to most of us :)